Performing superposed epoch analysis on time series data
I have a set of events on which I want to perform superposed epoch analysis(SEA). My event list is such that I took 3 days before the event start and 7 days after it. So total length of each event is 10 days.
Here is how the plot's axis should look like sample image for an idea
The sample data for HILDCAA_list_SEA is:
HILDCAA_list_SEA
The sample .cdf data for All.zip in the code can be accessed from this link:URL for every date given in HILDCAA_list_SEA.
# Function to extract .cdf files from a zip file
def extract_cdf_files(zip_file_path, output_dir):
    with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(output_dir)
    print(f"Extracted .cdf files from {zip_file_path} to {output_dir}")

# Function to read data from .cdf files in a directory
def read_data(directory):
    all_data = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith('.cdf'):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                try:
                    data = dm.fromCDF(file_path)
                    # Assuming you want to extract 'FEDU', 'L', and 'Epoch' data
                    if 'FEDU' in data and 'L' in data and 'Epoch' in data:
                        all_data.append({
                            'FEDU': data['FEDU'],
                            'L': data['L'],
                            'Epoch': data['Epoch']
                        })
                    else:
                        print(f"Required data not found in file: {file_path}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error processing file {file_path}: {e}")
                    continue
    return all_data

# Function to perform 2D SEA analysis
def perform_sea_analysis(data, events, bins, sea_cols, y_col, y_dim, seastats):
    # Log the data before performing SEA
    # Replace infinity values with NaN to properly calculate statistics
    logdata = data.copy()
    # Extract 'FEDU' data from each dictionary and apply log10
    logdata_FEDU = [np.log10(d['FEDU']) for d in data]
    # Replace infinity values with NaN in the log-transformed 'FEDU' data
    for i, d in enumerate(logdata_FEDU):
        logdata_FEDU[i][np.isinf(d)] = np.nan
    
    # Flatten the list of 'Epoch' data
    flattened_epoch_data = [epoch for d in data for epoch in d['Epoch']]
    
    # Ensure all arrays have the same length
    min_len = min(len(logdata_FEDU), len(flattened_epoch_data))
    logdata_FEDU = logdata_FEDU[:min_len]
    flattened_epoch_data = flattened_epoch_data[:min_len]
    
    # Create DataFrame with the extracted data
    logdata = pd.DataFrame({'FEDU': logdata_FEDU, 'L': [d['L'] for d in data][:min_len], 'Epoch': flattened_epoch_data})
    
    # Convert 'Epoch' column to datetime format and set it as the index
    logdata['Epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(logdata['Epoch'])
    logdata.set_index('Epoch', inplace=True)
    
    # Print out the column names to verify if 'FEDU' is present
    print(logdata.columns)
    
    # Perform the 2D SEA analysis
    sea2d, meta = sean(logdata, events, bins, cols=sea_cols, seastats=seastats, y_col=y_col, y_dimensions=y_dim)

    return sea2d, meta

#usage
zip_file_path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/AB/cdf/All.zip"  # Path to your local zip file
output_dir = "extracted_data"  # Directory to extract .cdf files
# Load the event list and place the epoch times into appropriate format
HILDCAAlist = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\AB\HILDCAA_list_SEA.xlsx', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0, 1, 2, 3])
HILDCAAlist = HILDCAAlist.reset_index(drop=False)
starts = HILDCAAlist['Start_date_epoch']
epochs = HILDCAAlist['Event_start']
ends = HILDCAAlist['End_date_epoch']
events = [starts, epochs, ends]

bins = [20, 120]

# Set the columns to run the analysis on
sea_cols = ['FEDU']

# Specify the y parameters for the 2D SEA
y_col = 'L'
ymin = 2.5
ymax = 5.5
y_spacing = 0.2
y_dim = [ymin, ymax, y_spacing]

# Define the statistics to use
seastats = {'median': np.nanmedian}

# Extract .cdf files from zip
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
extract_cdf_files(zip_file_path, temp_dir)

# Load downloaded data
data = read_data(temp_dir)

# Perform the 2D SEA analysis
sea2d, meta = perform_sea_analysis(data, events, bins, sea_cols, y_col, y_dim, seastats)

# Get the columns that the SEA was performed on from the returned metadata
cols = meta['sea_cols']

# Grab the y metadata for plotting
ymeta = meta['y_meta']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(cols), sharex=True, squeeze=True, figsize=(5, 3.5))

# Loop over columns that were analyzed
for c, ax in zip(cols, axes):
    mask = sea2d.columns.str.startswith(c)
    hb = ax.imshow(sea2d.loc[:, mask].to_numpy().transpose(), cmap='inferno',
                   origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=[sea2d.index.min(), sea2d.index.max(), min(ymeta['edges'])])
    ax.set_ylabel(c)
    cb = fig.colorbar(hb, ax=ax, label='log(flux)')

axes[len(cols) - 1].set_xlabel('Normalized Time')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Welcome to SO. All you've done is post code and asked what is wrong with it. At least give us a way to reproduce the outcome. Better still, tell us what part of the code is causing the problem and we can then help

Please read it carefully, I have attached the sample image. Also, when I tried reading the data using this code, it is unable to read FEDU

are you saying the read_data line is throwing an error?

Yes. The function def read_data():

In that case, please rewrite the question. You need to tell us what the problem is. You say in the question you want to plot something, but are now saying the problem is reading the data in. In that, case why are you posting code after the error? This is very confusing to anyone reading the question, who will rightly assume the final line is throwing the error
